right-to-left ligatures with luatex
In a comment to my answer to this question, it was pointed out that when \textdir TRT is set, ligatures seem to be formed before the text direction is reversed (I have no idea if that is the correct mental model). Here's an example.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

first {\textdir TRT first}

\end{document}


In that answer, I give a temporary workaround of just disabling ligatures using the fontspec option Ligatures=CommonOff. How can one keep ligatures enabled but following the direction of the text? The luatex manual is, shall we say, scant on details.
Edit
As David rightly points out, my example does not show the full range of behavior. Since there is no if ligature, I would not expect tsrif to have any ligatures. But if the word was motif, I'd expect fitom to have an fi ligature. Here's the current behavior.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

motif {\textdir TRT motif}

\end{document}


David's comment suggests that encoded in ligatures are LTR/RTL status, in which case it's unlikely Latin Modern has any RTL ligatures. Is this correct?
If my request is not possible, a description of luatex's text processing procedure in regards to forming ligatures, line breaks, text direction, etc., would make a good answer as well.

If you were using a font range designed for rtl then the ligatures would work naturally in that direction, latin modern doesn't have any ligatures designed for rtl so what you show is what i'd expect. By "keep ligatures enabled" do you mean you want a reversed if  ligaure in tsrif or do you mean that if you had started with bifocal you would get an fi ligature in  lacofib

@DavidCarlisle Oh that's a good point, I should have thought of that. In this case I'd expect no ligature in tsrif. But if the word was motif, I'd expect an fi ligature in fitom. I'll add this to the question

@DavidCarlisle Sorry I didn't carefully read your comment, yes your bifocal example is what I'd expect
